# Why I have this error message when I try to add a new constructor to a class that extend another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, constructor

I have the following problem:

I have a class named **PdfReport** that extends another class named **iTextDocumentBase** declared in this way:

```
public class PdfVulnerability : iTextDocumentBase
    {
    private DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln currentVuln;
    ...................................
    ...................................
    }
```

Into this class I am trying to add a new constructor that take a specific object as paramether, this one:

```
    public PdfVulnerability(DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln currentVuln){
        this.currentVuln = currentVuln;
    }
```

My problem is when I add this constructor to the previous **PdfReport** class, Visual studio give me the following error message:

> 'PdfReport.iTextDocumentBase' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 0 arguments

Why I obtain this error message when I try to add a new constructor to a class that extends another class?

Tnx

Comment: Could you post code about the PdfReport?

Comment: Do you mean that `PdfReport` extends `PdfVulnerability`? It's not clear where `iTextDocumentBase` really comes in here... (Also given the error message, it sounds like `PdfReport` might be the namespace, not the type name...) Posting a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would make it much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a class's constructor *always* calls its base class's constructor - either explicitly or implicitly.

In your case, since you didn't specify a call to any base class's constructor, a call to a constructor with 0 parameters is inferred. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
public PdfVulnerability(DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln currentVuln) : base()
{
    this.currentVuln = currentVuln;
}
```

And, apparently, this constructor doesn't exist in the base class `iTextDocumentBase`.

Check which constructors the base class provides, and call one of them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If base class doesn't have parameter less constructor defined and Child class doesn't call the base class constructor along with child class constructor. this error will occur. You have to call specific base class constructor with child class constructor